# Derivative of Dirac delta of f(x)

Tags: derivatives, dirac-delta

I'm trying to prove this relation:
$(\delta (f(x)))' = f'(x) \delta' (f(x)) $,
where $f(x)$ is a monotone function. I just end up tangled in different derivatives of Dirac delta function or derivatives of $f(x)$ and I can't solve it. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by $\delta(f(x))$?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It's a composition of Delta function with another function f(x).

Comment: I have no idea what the composition of $\delta$ and $f$ might mean, since $\delta$ is not actually a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: For example $\delta$ is the limit (in the sense of distributions) of a sequence of functions. Do you see a way to define $\delta(f(x))$ as the limit (in the sense of distributions) of some sequence of functions ? (assuming a few conditions on $f$) Same for $\delta'$ and $\delta'(f(x))$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Isn’t $\delta(0\ne x\in\Bbb R)=0, \delta(0)=\infty$ making it have one output for each input and therefore a function?

Comment: @TymaGaidash No.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just had to integrate both sides and then use substitution: $f(x) =t$ and then I got the same value on both sides of the equation.
Thank you to everyone who tried to help me with this problem!

Comment: More to the point (since you should always understand Dirac-$\delta$ statements as claims about integrals),$$\int_{\Bbb R}(\delta(f(x)))^\prime g^\prime(f(x))dx=\int_{\Bbb R}\delta^\prime(t)g^\prime(t)dt=\int_{\Bbb R}f^\prime(x)\delta^\prime(f(x))g^\prime(f(x))dx$$for a family, to be determined in an exercise best left to the reader, of functions $g$.